# How to Connect to Azure database using the standard dotnet web template

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am super excited to start developing .NET on my Mac but getting frustrated trying to figure it all out. So I have a WebApplication created by calling yo aspnet and out of the box it works great. It comes with a connection to a local db stored in the project. Where I am having trouble is connecting it to a remote DB hosted in my azure portal.

My Connection string below directly from my azure portal. I have updated my appsettings.json "DefaultConnection" property to this value (with the username and password missing below) and I am getting errors like "ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'." I have tried several different connection strings and none are working.

Admittedly I am new to all of this so I am probably missing something simple but in searching online I have yet to find the solution.

```
Server=tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=LH;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

For reference here is my whole appsettings.json (without username & passwrod...)

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=LH.db"
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=lighthouseFSQ;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={Username};Password={Password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"        
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. FYI I did try this in Windows VS2015 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `dotnet new -t web` tempalte uses SQLite database, so only changing the connection string is not sufficient to change the provider.

You also need to remove the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` package from `project.json` and replace it with `Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer` (assuming you are using the SQLServer of Azure). Then in your `Startup.cs` you need to replace the

```
// Add framework services.
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

with

```
// Add framework services.
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and change the namespaces if necessary.

**Update**

In project.json you just need to change the dependency with Sqlite.

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
  ...
  }
}
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
  ...
  }
}
```

If there is also a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design` ch ange that too to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design` too, it's there for scaffolding etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes perfect sense. Would it be to much to ask for a sample exactly what I need to change in project.json I see where I need to change it but it's not liking what I am putting in.

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },

Comment: I've updated, but its really just the dependency section

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. I was getting lost on the version after finding conflicting examples online.